# Why did my log file get created with USC-2 Little Endian encoding?

Tags: powershell

I have a Powershell command that runs an executable and redirects all the output to a log file. It works and the log contains the correct text but the file is in USC-2 Little Endian format which is not readable by some other programs. When I use batch to do the same thing it creates the log in UTF-8. I can switch to batch as an option but my paths are UNC and batch prints a bunch of warnings about that. That's why I am try to use Powershell for this task.

Here is the script:

```
& .\rh.exe /connstring="Server=MYSERVER;Database=DB1;UID=U1;PWD=***" `
    /files=Folder1 `
    /versionfile=Version.xml `
    /vx=version `
    /repo=Repo1 `
    > test.txt *>&1
```

When I open test.txt with Notepad++ and click the Encoding menu it shows USC-2 Little Endian as the selected encoding.

**Update:**

I tried this alternative and I now get UTF-8 encoding.

```
& .\rh.exe /connstring="Server=MYSERVER;Database=DB1;UID=U1;PWD=***" `
    /files=Folder1 `
    /versionfile=Version.xml `
    /vx=version `
    /repo=Repo1 `
    | Out-File test.txt -Encoding utf8
```

This raises another question though. I was using *>&1 to make sure that all outputs get redirected and not just STDOUT. Should I add this to the end of the Out-File like so or does Out-File capture all forms of output?:

```
... | Out-File test.txt -Encoding utf8 *>&1
```

Comment: As noted in [`about_Redirection`](https://technet.microsoft.com/library/hh847746.aspx) help topic, file redirection use Unicode encoding. BTW, why `> test.txt *>&1` instead of `*> test.txt`?

Comment: @PetSerAl I found a sample somewhere with the *>&1 syntax. I did not know about the *>. I tried it and it works the same way. I still get USC-2 Little Endian encoding on the test.txt file.

Comment: You have to use `*>&1` before `Out-File`: `... *>&1 | Out-File test.txt -Encoding utf8`